# Hair Particle sitting half in plane

Tags: particles, hair

I am trying to use a particle system to place a model of some grass and trees on a plane in my scene. The objects are being placed on the plane but half of them is under the plane. I have read the one other question relating to this problem that I could find, but their solution didn't work.

[image: Trees and grass clipping plane]

Comment: check whether you applied scale. if this doesn't help, please provide blend file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because particle system uses **the origin** to put hair. Move the hair particle's origin down - Cursor to selected like vertex at the base, then Origin to 3D cursor. Then it works as expected.